# Oracle: Avoiding NULL value in to_date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, to-date

I have a functional select statement that has a where clause, in the where clause there is a statement like so...

> to_date(camp.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= to_date(:from_date,
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

However, if camp.start_date is NULL or has no rows then it is throwing an exception -

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

camp.start_date is actually a VARCHAR2 that I need to convert into a date, (yes I know it probably should be a date field but I don't have the options to change this).

I tried something like this...

```
to_date(NVL(camp.start_date,SYSDATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= 
to_date(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Which still is giving me an error.  Also tried

> where camp.start_date is not null and to_date(camp.start_date,
>   'MM/DD/YYYY') >= to_date(:from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

same issue.  What is the best way around this?  Basically to_date is exploding and throwing an error when camp.start_date is not a valid date.

Comment: Also for some reason this is ok in db_visualizer but it throws an error using Rails?

Answer (score 12):

If `start_date` is NULL, no exception is thrown.

```
select to_date( null, 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) 
  from dual
```

is a perfectly valid SQL statement that returns NULL.

The error you are getting strongly implies that at least some of the rows in the `start_date` column are not actually strings in the format you expect or that map to invalid dates (i.e. the string '13/35/2007').  You can write a function that tests to see whether a string can be converted to a date and return either the converted date or a NULL.  You can then use that instead of `to_date`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_date( p_str    IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_format IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN DATE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_date( p_str, p_format );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS
  THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

and then use `my_to_date` instead of `to_date`.  That should eliminate the error you're getting.  You'll probably want to clean up the data, though, to get rid of the invalid strings.

Comment: That was it, some of the dates are like so 1/1/2013 perhaps they should be 01/01/2013?

Comment: @HelloWorld - That would convert successfully, it's not a matter of leading 0's.  You can look for rows where `my_to_date( camp.start_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') is null and camp.start_date is not null` to see what the invalid strings are.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert sysdate to the valid char string format:

```
to_date(NVL(start_date,to_char(SYSDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')), 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= 
to_date(from_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
NVL(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YYYY'),' ')
```

This will convert the date to string format and then to empty string.

Comment: A space (`' '`), not an empty string (`''`). And only on days when sysdate is null.

Answer (score -2):

Does

```
NVL(TO_DATE(start_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),SYSDATE) >= from_date
```

make more sence if `from_date` has a not null date type value?
If `from_date` can be null or is not a date value then do this?

```
NVL(TO_DATE(start_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),SYSDATE) >= NVL(TO_DATE(from_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),SYSDATE)
```

Something like comparing apples to apples?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)